# AFNetworking - Asynchronous upload task that can have files queued for upload (w/ progress)

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, swift, afnetworking-2

What I want to do:

1. Start a multipart upload of a video
2. Before it finishes uploading add another video to be uploaded when 1. is completed
3. Show the progress as videos are added

I've looked around but could only find help on creating an upload task for a batch upload, and no information on how to add to an existing upload task.

Thoughts?

Also I'm using swift, but I don't mind ObjC answers :)

Comment: You're basically going to have to replicate the upload block functionality, probably using a new NSOperation subclass.  That's what I wound up doing when faced with a similar problem.  Part of the issue is that the AFNetworking upload block functionality is based on using operation dependency to schedule the completion block.

Comment: That sounds really gross, but I kind of expected the solution to be something similar. Do you have any examples of this being done that I could take a look at?

Comment: @BZMWillemsen i'm making you class that make it for you update it here soon when i finish :), just let me get your request... you want upload several movies to server with queue operation with progress ?

Comment: @DekelMaman: Yes, upload several movies at a time with a queue, so that I can add movies to the upload task as previous ones are uploading. Movies added to the queue will be put last in the queue but will get uploaded in the same task. And to be able to view progress of the upload.

Comment: @BZMWillemsen the videos are token from the device album ?

Comment: @DekelMaman the devices will be recorded on the device, and I will be storing them myself. A user will record a video, I will save it locally, and then I will add it to the queue to be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I create class for you that make it 
Go to my git and check it...

https://github.com/dekelm8/QueueUploading

I hop you can handle with the server side alone , the .php file :)

Hop It's helping you, if yes please mark as solved :)

Comment: @BZMWillemsen check if this helping you

Comment: Checking, I'll get back to ya in a bit :)